# « S'appelle » ou « appelée » pour emplacements?

Tags: verbes, conjugaison, verbes-pronominaux

I'm writing down a paragraph where I introduce myself, and am doing a quick grammar check through Google Translate (yes, I know it is terrible), before I ask my French teacher tomorrow. I actually seem to have run into something interesting.

If I type in:

> J'habite dans une petite rue s'appelle ___.

It translates to "I live in a small street called ___" except if I then translate it back into French:

> Je vis dans une petite rue appelée ___.

Forgetting about *vis* because I don't care about the mis-translation, the verb *appeler* looks to me like the passé composé definition, except it's also like a few other ones. (I'm only in Year. 11 and so far we've only gone as far as présent, or though I try to stretch further, so really, I have no idea what conjugation it is).

When I translate simply:

> a small street called ___.

It actually translates with "s'appelle" instead.

My question is, is this just a semantic error with Google Translate and I am in fact correct by using `s'appelle`, or am I indeed wrong?

Merci.

Comment: Welcome to French Language. Nice first question.

Comment: GT has a hard time discerning that *s'appelle* has no interpretation if not preceded by a subject (a regular noun phrase or the pronoun *qui*, for example). To generalize, GT doesn't know what to do with grammatical errors. Its model associates words and translations, and as far as it can see *s'appelle* is the main contributor to meanings like "called, named, calls itself". It always tries to produce a translation, so that's what it gives you. Hence, it's not very useful as a grammar checker. ... Even if it gets lucky sometimes and turns meaningless French into meaningless English for you. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*"J'habite dans une petit rue s'appelle"* is grammatically incorrect.

You can say either *une petit**e** rue **[qui](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/relative-pronouns-que-qui/)** s'appelle* (literally "a small street that is called") or *une petit**e** rue appelée* ("a small street called").

*Appelée* is a form of the [past participle](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/past-participle/) (the e at the end makes it feminine, to agree with *rue* - the base form is *appelé*.) French, like English, often uses past participles as adjectives.

Comment: Ahhh! I forgot the *qui*! Merci beaucoup!

Answer (score 2):

The verb *s'appeler* is a [reflexive verb](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/french/grammar/verbsf/reflexiverev1.shtml). As is sometimes the case in French the reflexive verb is used where English would use a passive voice.

> une rue qui s'appelle ...

would translate into English with:  a street (that is) called...,
(you usually only keep the past participle).

What Google Translate does is to keep the passive voice when translating back into French, making a word for word translation. It is not wrong but it does not sound idiomatic French. Using *s'appeler* is much better, in that case.

> J'habite dans une petite rue qui s'appelle ___.

Other examples of instances where French would use a reflexive verb instead of a passive voice:

- Ce livre se lit facilement.
- Cette boisson se garde au frigo.
- Ce gâteau est tellement bon qu'il se mange facilement.